# Merge two Mat images into one

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have a problem. I have an image. Then I have to split the image into two equal parts. I made this like that (the code is compiled, everything is good):

```
Mat image_temp1 = image(Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows/2)).clone();
Mat image_temp2 = image(Rect(0, image.rows/2, image.cols, image.rows/2)).clone();
```

Then I have to change each part independently and finally to merge into one. I have no idea how to make this correctly. How I should merge this 2 parts of image into one image?
Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLDK7.jpg

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is several way to do this, but the best way I found is to use `cv::hconcat(mat1, mat2, dst)` for horizontal merge or`cv::vconcat(mat1, mat2, dst)` for vertical.

Don't forget to take care of empty matrix merge case !

Comment: Whoa! I can't believe that these functions absent in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Seems that [cv::Mat::push_back](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html?highlight=push_back#void%20Mat::push_back%28const%20Mat&%20m%29) is exactly what are you looking for:

> C++: void Mat::push_back(const Mat& m) : Adds elements to the bottom of the matrix.
>
> ```
> Parameters:    
>     m – Added line(s).
> ```
>
> The methods add one or more elements to the bottom of the matrix. When elem is
>   Mat , its **type and the number of columns must be the same** as in the
>   container matrix.

Optionally, you could create new `cv::Mat` of proper size and place image parts directly into it:

```
Mat image_temp1 = image(Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows/2)).clone();
Mat image_temp2 = image(Rect(0, image.rows/2, image.cols, image.rows/2)).clone();
...
cv::Mat result(image.rows, image.cols);
image_temp1.copyTo(result(Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows/2)));
image_temp2.copyTo(result(Rect(0, image.rows/2, image.cols, image.rows/2));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Mat newImage = image.clone();
Mat image_temp1 = newImage(Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows/2));
Mat image_temp2 = newImage(Rect(0, image.rows/2, image.cols, image.rows/2));
```

By not using `clone()` to create the temp images, you're implicitly modifying `newImage` when you modify the temp images without the need to merge them again. After changing `image_temp1` and `image_temp2`, `newImage` will be exactly the same as if you had split, modified, and then merged the subimages.