# How to remove keypoint-matches lines in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to remove lines and keypoints. 
Is there a function other than `drawMatches` or can I make lines and keypoints invisible in `drawMatches`?

```
Mat img_matches;
drawMatches( img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
           good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
           std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );
```

[image: A picture]

Comment: so why do you call `drawMatches` if you don't want to _draw matches_?

Comment: @Miki For img_matches. I draw green lines using line function.  
    
    line( img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f( img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4 );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mask out all matches with the `matchesMask` parameter:

```
Mat img_matches;
std::vector<char> mask_matches(good_matches.size(), 0);
drawMatches( 
    img_object, 
    keypoints_object, 
    img_scene, 
    keypoints_scene,
    good_matches, 
    img_matches, 
    Scalar::all(-1), 
    Scalar::all(-1),
    mask_matches, // <----
    DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS 
);
```

---

Since you basically just need the two images side-by-side, you can just create the image by yourself. You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33262398/5008845).