# How can i merge the images?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have several images in one of my folders and I want to merge all of them to make it into one image. For example, if I have all the alphabets into picture form like `A B C D E F G H` and so on and I want all of them in one image like this `ABCDEFGH` and so on. So, pls if anyone can help me.

**The which I have tried is:**

```
int main()
{
    // Load images
    Mat3b img1 = imread("C:\\Users\\leno\\Documents\\640x480dove\\OCR_REF\\FONT-0.bmp");
    Mat3b img2 = imread("C:\\Users\\leno\\Documents\\640x480dove\\OCR_REF\\FONT-1.bmp");
    //Mat3b img3 = imread("C:\\Users\\leno\\Documents\\640x480dove\\OCR_REF\\FONT-2.bmp");

    // Get dimension of final image
    int rows = max(img1.rows, img2.rows);
    //int rows1 = max(img1.rows, img3.rows);
    int cols = img1.cols + img2.cols ;
    //int cols1 = img1.cols + img3.cols;

    // Create a black image
    Mat3b res(rows, cols, Vec3b(0, 0, 0));
    //Mat3b res1(rows1,cols1, Vec3b(0,0,0));

    // Copy images in correct position
    img1.copyTo(res(Rect(0, 0, img1.cols, img1.rows)));
    img2.copyTo(res(Rect(img1.cols, 0, img2.cols, img2.rows)));
    //img3.copyTo(res1(Rect(img1.cols, 0, img3.cols, img3.rows)));
    //img3.copyTo(res1(Rect(0, 0, img3.cols, img3.rows)));

    // Show result
    imshow("Img 1", img1);
    imshow("Img 2", img2);
    imshow("Result", res);
    //imshow("result", res1);
    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read all your images as `img1, img2, img3, img4` ... then simply use [cv2.hconcat()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4676b1376cdc4e528dab6bd9edc51c1a) to concatenate them in horizontal direction, there is no need to craete a new `Mat` by summing up the dimensions, OpenCV would handle it internally for you. Just make sure that all images have same height.

Comment: Thanks, but it didnt work. The hconcat function took only two images. As soon as i added third image to the function it generated erorr.

Comment: You need to pass all the images in a `list` as first argument. Other option is to use `np.hstack()`

Comment: @janam check this stackoverflow post: [Merge two Mat images into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27296170/merge-two-mat-images-into-one)

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I have made a list of img but in hconcate it took only upto 4 imaged. I want n number of images. Can help me with it? Thank you.

Comment: No code required, just use **ImageMagick** in Terminal `convert A.png B.png C.png D.png +append result.png` or in `bash` just `convert [A-H].png +append result.png`

Comment: As @ZdaR mentioned, If all the images are of same size  hconcat must work. please post your pictures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that `cv::hconcat()` works with any arbitrary number of images, here is a sample code snippet for demo purposes:

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat mat1 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(100, 150, 50));
    cv::Mat mat2 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(0, 150, 50));
    cv::Mat mat3 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(100, 10, 50));
    cv::Mat mat4 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(100, 150, 150));
    cv::Mat mat5 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(200, 150, 250));
    cv::Mat mat6 = cv::Mat(10, 10, CV_8UC3, cv::Scalar(100, 200, 0));


    std::vector<cv::Mat> vec = {mat1, mat2, mat3, mat4, mat5, mat6};

    cv::Mat final;
    cv::hconcat(vec, final);
    cv::imwrite("../debug.png", final);
}
```

And the output is:

[image]

Comment: Can u help me with the code having both hconcat and vconcat, So that i can merge it in an image form.